# Is this formula true for $n\geq 1$:$4^n+2 \equiv 0 \mod 6 $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, decimal-expansion

Is this formula true for $n\geq 1$:$$4^n+2 \equiv 0 \mod 6 $$.

Note :I have tried for some values of $n\geq 1$ i think it's true such that
:I used the sum digits of this number:$N=114$,$$1+1+4\equiv 0 \mod 6,1²+1²+4²\equiv 0 \mod 6,1^3+1^3+4^3\equiv 0 \mod 6,\cdots $$ ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, because $4^2\equiv 4\pmod{6}$, and hence $4^n\equiv 4\pmod{6}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: ok thank you , my goal is the sum of  power  digits of 114 the only number satisfing this

Comment: example :6 not divise 141 or 411

Answer (score 3):

For all $n$,
$$
4^n\equiv1^n\equiv1\pmod{3}
$$
For all $n\gt0$,
$$
4^n\equiv0^n\equiv0\pmod{2}
$$
Therefore, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem
$$
4^n\equiv4\pmod{6}
$$
and therefore, for all $n\gt0,$
$$
4^n+2\equiv0\pmod{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For a less number theoretic approach, let $S_n$ be the statement that $4^n + 2$ is divisible by 6. Clearly $S_1$ is true since $4^1 + 2 = 6$. Now assuming that $4^k + 2$ is divisible by 6,
\begin{align*}
4^{k+1} + 2 &= 4\cdot4^n + 2 \\
&= 4\cdot4^n + 4\cdot2 - 6  \\
&= 4(4^n + 2) - 6,
\end{align*}
we immediately have that $4^{k+1} + 2$ is divisible by 6, so the induction is complete.

The other answers are far more elegant, however, and you should lean towards using modular arithmetic to solve these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make $\pmod2$ and $\pmod 3$ separately.
It very simple.
$2$ divides $4^n+2$ so for the first step we get $4^n+2\equiv0\pmod2$ Obviously.

As $4\equiv1\mod3$, $4^n\equiv1\pmod3 \space \forall n>0$, and therefore $4^n+2\equiv0\pmod3$

$4^n+2\equiv0\pmod2$ and $4^n+2\equiv0\pmod3$

It follows that $4^n+2\equiv0\pmod6$

Q.E.D.